# Fizz Buzz Lightyear

Tags: code-golf

In the wake of the many (two?) FizzBuzz-related challenges posted recently on PPCG, I've been tempted to come up with my own. Behold...

## Fizz Buzz Lightyear

Write a program or function that takes an integer `n` and prints out `FizzBuzz` for any number divisible by 15, `Fizz` for any number divisible by 3, and `Buzz` for any number divisible by 5, up to (and including) `n`. Output for all `i` must be followed by a newline. But there's a twist!

For every third time you print `Buzz`, Buzz Lightyear finally heeds your call and crash lands in your program. He then introduces himself - but since he crash landed, some of what he said gets mixed up with your program's output:

```
Buzz Lightyear, Space Ranger, Universe Protection Unit.
FizzBuzz Lightyear, Space Ranger, Universe Protection Unit.
```

*(that is, only append  `Lightyear, Space Ranger, Universe Protection Unit.` to `Buzz` or `FizzBuzz` - whatever it is you'd have displayed otherwise. Note the leading space)*

However, Buzz Lightyear, being the Space Ranger he is, has very acute hearing, and so *printing `FizzBuzz` will count towards your `Buzz` count*.

Then, Buzz hangs around to defend your computer from all of that evil output, until you hit another number that's divisible by 5 (or 15, since those are divisible by 5, too). What that means is until you have to print `Buzz` (or `FizzBuzz`) again, you don't print anything at all.

When you finally reach that condition, Buzz departs:

```
To infinity and beyond!
```

## Example Output

This is the expected output for `n = 25`: *(notice how it skips 16 through 19)*

```
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
Fizz
7
8
Fizz
Buzz
11
Fizz
13
14
FizzBuzz Lightyear, Space Ranger, Universe Protection Unit.
To infinity and beyond!
Fizz
22
23
Fizz
Buzz
```

## Rules

Optional trailing newline is acceptable.

This is code golf; as such, shortest code, in bytes, wins.

Assume given `n` is valid *and greater than or equal to 15* (which is when the challenge first deviates from standard fizzbuzz)

Buzz greets you when the "Buzz counter" (which counts both `Buzz` and `FizzBuzz`) hits 3; he departs when the next `Buzz` (including, again, both `Buzz` and `FizzBuzz`) is printed.

The number in which he departs does not count towards the next "Buzz counter"; you should instead start counting the `Buzz`es again from 0. For instance, a program running with `n = 25` (example output) should end with a "Buzz counter" of 1, since that's how many times `Buzz` was printed since the last time he departed.

In case `n` falls between one of Buzz's arrivals and one of his departures (i.e., he's still there - you're not printing anything), graceful termination is expected. Therefore, the last line of output would be his introduction

Standard loopholes are forbidden.

Comment: Can you clarify the expected behavior when `n` falls in-between Buzz Lightyear's arrival and his departure?

Comment: Simply quit the program. I'll edit the rules in a second

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript (ES6), <strike>182</strike> 175 bytes

- **-7 bytes**: Moved Buzz Lightyear logic into Buzz ternary expression.

```js
f=(n,s=i=b=_='')=>i++<n?f(n,s+`${(i%3?_:'Fizz')+(i%5?_:`Buzz${++b%3?_:` Lightyear, Space Ranger, Universe Protection Unit.${(i+=5)>n?_:`
To infinity and beyond!`}`}`)||i}
`):s
```

```html
<!-- snippet demo: -->
<input oninput=o.innerHTML=f(this.value)>
<pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>185</s> <s>178</s> 172 bytes

```python
for i in range(input()):
 if-~i%20<16:print i%20/19*"To infinity and beyond!"or i%3/2*"Fizz"+i%5/4*"Buzz"+i%20/14*" Lightyear, Space Ranger, Universe Protection Unit."or-~i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#JY67DoJAEEV7v2LchATwgeAjQqwsrCyMjw9YYcBpZsk6mEDhr@NuLM9N7rl3rI0FAmKwmhsMidtOwigqJkD14ktBtjqku6K1xAKekjSP1d24Rk1M0oPmCp7YG66myruCdZLF6kTDoGYUbJNNrI7dH3zbIZypeUmP2s7h1uoS4eq3HT2YPmjfCBdrBEshwz6TpTO7M@OY738)

#### Explanation

Observe: Buzz Lightyear arrives on the third "buzz number" and departs on the fourth. "Buzz numbers" are the multiples of five. Thus, Buzz's movements happen on a cycle of length 20.

We loop over each `i` from 0 through input-1. (This means that `i` is always one less than the actual number we're considering.)

Using `-~i` as a shortcut for `i+1`, `if-~i%20<16:` checks if `i+1`, mod 20, is 15 or under. (If it's 16 to 19, Buzz Lightyear is present and we don't want to output anything.)

Inside the if statement, we want to print `To infinity and beyond!` on every multiple of 20--that is, every time `i%20` is 19. (Remember that `i` is one less than the actual number.) Since `i%20` will never be greater than 19, `i%20/19` will be 1 in the desired case, <1 otherwise. Python 2, conveniently, truncates floats when multiplying by strings, so `i%20/19*"..."` gives the full string if `i%20` is 19, otherwise `""`.

If the above case applies, we don't print anything else. But if the first expression is `""` (which is falsy), we use `or` to keep going. The expressions for `Fizz`, `Buzz`, and the introduction are computed similarly to the above and added together.

Finally, if none of these cases applies, we print the number itself with `-~i`.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>97</s> <s>93</s> 90 bytes

```
>GN"FizzBuzz"2äN35SÖÏJ)˜1(è“To infinity€ƒ—°!“)N20%©_è®15Q” Lightyear,‡²ìÓ,ªÜŠí‰¿.”×J®16‹i,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#AYUAev//PkdOIkZpenpCdXp6IjLDpE4zNVPDlsOPSinLnDEow6jigJxUbyBpbmZpbml0eeKCrMaS4oCUwrAh4oCcKU4yMCXCqV/DqMKuMTVR4oCdIExpZ2h0eWVhcizigKHCssOsw5MswqrDnMWgw63igLDCvy7igJ3Dl0rCrjE24oC5aSz//zQx)

Explanation to come after further golfing.

**Alternative 97 byte version**

```
>G"FizzBuzz"2ä” Lightyear,‡²ìÓ,ªÜŠí‰¿.”)˜N•9¨•3äR%15%_ÏJ“To infinity€ƒ—°!“)N20ÖèN)˜é®èN20%15›i\},
```